# Computing difference between Spark DataFrames

Tags: apache-spark

I have two `DataFrames` `df1` and `df2`. I want to compute a third ``` DataFrame ``df3 ``` such that `df3 = (df1 - df2)` i.e all elements present in df1 but not in df2. Is there any in-built library function to achieve that something like `df1.subtract(df2)`?

Answer (score 4):

You are probably searching for `except` function: http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

From the description:

> def except(other: DataFrame): DataFrame
>
> Returns a new DataFrame containing rows in this frame but not in
> another frame. This is equivalent to EXCEPT in SQL.